# How to execute a file with a different extension's associated application?

Tags: delphi, winapi, shellexecute, file-association

In my application, I would like to be able to execute a file with an arbitrary name and extension using *the program associated with a different extension*.

For example, say I have a file called `file.dat`, but I wanted to open it with Notepad, as if it was named `file.txt` or `file.dat.txt`. Also, I don't have permission to rename the file, so that's out of the question.

If the file *were* called `file.txt`, I could call [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153.aspx). But that fails when calling `file.dat`; Windows complains that there’s no association for that file.

I don't want to hardcode a specific executable, because (in the example above) the end user could have associated `.txt` files with Wordpad instead of Notepad. In such a case, I’d want my `file.dat` to be opened with Wordpad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) and specify the `lpClass` member of the [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx) struct. Note that you must include `SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME` in the `fMask` member.

For instance, set `lpClass` to `'.txt'` to request that the file be opened with the program associated with the `.txt` extension.